# What are the fundamentals of optionally compiling a library or requiring DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll

I would like to write a component with the ability for a developer to either require a DLL or include a unit in their app which compiles the library with the project, without the DLL.

For example, let's say it's called "MyLibrary". If I include `MyLibrary` in the uses clause, it will by default require that a DLL be distributed with the application. On the other hand, if another unit `MyLibraryImplementation` is in the uses clause, it will compile everything inside the app without requiring the DLL.

This component is inside a package installed into the IDE.

I'm not even sure the terminology for this, or anything about how to go about this. I'm very familiar with writing DLL's, and not looking for someone to write any full code.

What are the fundamental things I need to know to make this optional DLL possible?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are looking for. You would load a DLL at runtime through LoadLibrary. Including code in the application would be compiled through the source. The code itself would need to be written in such a way to support compiling to a DLL as well as normally. Are you looking for a code generator of sorts or a template for this type of solution?

Comment: @Graymatter As I said, I'm more than familiar with DLL's and don't want code necessarily. I just need to know what particular things are involved in accomplishing this DLL as an option.

Comment: I mean I have some fuzzy ideas of what's involved, but no clear picture, and don't want to jump to conclusions without knowing the common practice for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are struggling with. The code needs to look for the library. If it can find it, load it, import the functions, then it uses them. Otherwise it opts for the fallback behaviour.

Comment: You can use interfaces if you opt to use a Delphi package. You could create a package X.dpk. Both your application and the DLL would use the package. They don't have to use any other runtime packages. That would give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to Midas.DLL vs. MidasLib.pas? Midas.DLL is loaded on demand when some condition is met. Using MidasLib changes this condition and forces the Midas code to be compiled into the target, so the DLL is not required anymore. Have a look at DataSnap.DSIntf.pas and MidasLib,pas to study the details.

Comment: I also wonder why you want to make a choice statically through a uses change. Why not be dynamic? That gives the end user the most flexibility.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, perhaps for deploying only one exe to avoid DLL hell?

Comment: @UweRaabe I'm not suggesting anything that stops deploying a single exe. The programmer can still choose how to bind to the code, just at runtime rather than at compile time.

Comment: This question is one example of why you shouldn't post questions when you're drunk.

Comment: `Midas` is exactly what I was aiming for, I just couldn't think of which library it was which I had seen this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably won't find the result very satisfying. Delphi cannot directly load classes from a DLL. Instead, you'll need to define some class in your MyLibrary unit. You'll also have to implement most of the methods there. You're welcome to make those methods be little more than stubs that delegate all the work to functions in the DLL, though. In the stub constructor, call a DLL function that allocates a data structure and returns a handle. In all three other stub methods, pass that handle to the corresponding DLL functions along with the methods' other arguments.

You'll essentially have three parallel implementations of the class:

1. The one in MyLibrary.pas that's nothing but stubs.
2. The one in MyLibrary.dll that backs the stubs.
3. The one in MyLibraryImplementation.pas that does all the same things as the DLL, but internally.

You can probably avoid duplicating too much, but not completely.

You don't need to do any of this, though. For years, Delphi has already offered comparable functionality built in: packages.

If your customers want to have your class's implementation live in a separate module, they can choose the "build with runtime packages" option in their projects' linker settings. Disabling that setting will cause your code to be compiled in to their EXE files instead, and they won't need to distribute the BPL file anymore.

Comment: Upvote for suggesting packages. They are ideal for this.

Comment: I know about the classes, I actually recently answered someone else's struggles on that exact subject. I use interfaces - my question wasn't really about that. Just the fact that my class uses this DLL. But accepted for use of packages, which still wasn't the answer to my real question (which I lacked in explaining). I'm accepting your answer based on what I asked :-/ I forgot to mention that this DLL will be compatible with other languages.